# Azure Devops - Is there any way I can retrieve my committed local repository after a hard drive crash?

Tags: git, azure, crash, devops, commit

Previously with VSTS  having Workspaces, you could find your Commits again.
And also if an employee has left the company, you could access his work space and get the files.

Are we saying that Azure Devops with Git Doesn't store your local commits anywhere remotely?

Have I lost all my commits, after my hard drive crashed?

Comment: Git is a distributed version control system. Local commits exist only in your local repository unless you proactively push them to a remote repository (in this case your Azure Repo). So, yes: Un-pushed commits from your local repository are lost if the local repository is lost.

Comment: I'm afraid if those commits were not pushed anywhere and your hard drive crashed, yes, they're lost. My personal approach to Git is to have a second, private server where I push those local commits for work-in-progress multiple times a day if I am not ready to share them with my team yet on the official Git repo of the project.